# azure data factory how to fetch source distinct count and target distinct count for data validation

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am copying data from azure sql to azure storage. I need the validation for source and target like the record count for each column in source and destination also distinct record count for each column in source and destination.

The output must be in a table or file.

[image: requirement]

Comment: what's your table data look like? Does the table have the column like ID to count the rows? In usually, the sink file will have the same data with source.

Comment: nope. it has columns like name, amt, status

Comment: Hi @Ravali, You can use Data Flow [Surrogate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-surrogate-key) to create a key column for you source,  then we could get the rows for the sink side. Is that you want?

Comment: Hi @Leon, Thanks for the inputs. I have added a sample picture of the requirement.

Comment: what's the source/target distinct count? it's the count type of dept? If so, the only way is using data flow, it may be a little complex to achieve it. I noticed that you haven't accept others answer for now, may I know why?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, Thanks for the inputs. I'll try using the dataflows.

Comment: Hi @Ravali, may I post this as the answer then you can accept(mark) it?

Answer (score 0):

According my understanding, the source table and target are both sources.

Then you could use Data Flow to achieve that:

1. Source 1: source table--> use query to get the columnname, `sourcerowcount` and
   `sourcedistinctcount`.
2. Source 2: target table-->user query to get `targetrowcount` and
   `targetdistinctcount`.
3. [Join active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join): join this two source output

HTH.